# AVPlayer Volume Control

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, volume, avplayer

I want to create a button that mutes the audio from an AVPlayer.

Why can´t I use .volume with AVPlayer, only with AVAudioPlayer?
Is there another way to change the volume?

e.g `music.volume = 0.0;`

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Starting in iOS 7, simply call:

```
myAvPlayer.volume = 0;
```

Otherwise, you'll have to use the annoying `setAudioMix` solution. I'm detecting support for this in my app as follows:

```
if ([mPlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setVolume:)]) {
    mPlayer.volume = 0.0;
 } else {
     NSArray *audioTracks = mPlayerItem.asset.tracks;

     // Mute all the audio tracks
     NSMutableArray *allAudioParams = [NSMutableArray array];
     for (AVAssetTrack *track in audioTracks) {
         AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams =[AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];
         [audioInputParams setVolume:0.0 atTime:kCMTimeZero];
         [audioInputParams setTrackID:[track trackID]];
         [allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];
     }
     AVMutableAudioMix *audioZeroMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
     [audioZeroMix setInputParameters:allAudioParams];

     [mPlayerItem setAudioMix:audioZeroMix]; // Mute the player item
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Doug! I was looking for this for couple hours. Thankfully it's just setting one property on AVPLayer :D

Comment: A perfect, simple, beautiful answer!

Comment: @doug why did you change this to `1.0` - just a typo?

Comment: @CupawnTae wow that is a great question. Yea I was really sleepy and made a spurious correction lol. I changed it back.

Answer (score 3):

I used below code to mute AVPlayer.

```
 float volSet = 0 ;
 AVAsset *avAsset = [[avPlayer currentItem] asset] ;
NSArray *audioTracks = [avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] ;

 NSMutableArray *allAudioParams = [NSMutableArray array] ;
for(AVAssetTrack *track in audioTracks){
 AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters] ;
[audioInputParams setVolume:volSet atTime:kCMTimeZero] ;
 [audioInputParams setTrackID:[track trackID]] ;
 [allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];
}
 AVMutableAudioMix *audioVolMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix] ;
[audioVolMix setInputParameters:allAudioParams];
 [[avPlayer currentItem] setAudioMix:audioVolMix];
```

Comment: This works: [[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:0.0];

Answer (score 2):

best way is as following

```
  AVAssetTrack* assetTrackAudio = [arrayTracks objectAtIndex:0];

    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters* audioInputParams = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];
    [audioInputParams setVolume:currentVolume atTime:playerCursorStartPosition];
    [audioInputParams setTrackID:[assetTrackAudio trackID]];

    NSArray* audioParams = [NSArray arrayWithObject:audioInputParams];
    AVMutableAudioMix* audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
    [audioMix setInputParameters:audioParams];

    AVPlayerItem* item = [player currentItem];
    [item setAudioMix:audioMix];
```

Comment: I think it´s only working with AVAudioPlayer. When i use this with AVPlayer nothing happens.

Comment: @user2196602: It surely works with AVPlayer. Please check the [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1716/_index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link

[apple documentation for muting audio](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1716/_index.html)

Below is the code

```
 AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[self myAssetURL] options:nil];
NSArray *audioTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

// Mute all the audio tracks
NSMutableArray *allAudioParams = [NSMutableArray array];
for (AVAssetTrack *track in audioTracks) {
    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams =[AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];
    [audioInputParams setVolume:0.0 atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [audioInputParams setTrackID:[track trackID]];
    [allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];
}
AVMutableAudioMix *audioZeroMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
[audioZeroMix setInputParameters:allAudioParams];

// Create a player item
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
[playerItem setAudioMix:audioZeroMix]; // Mute the player item

// Create a new Player, and set the player to use the player item
// with the muted audio mix
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

// assign player object to an instance variable
self.mPlayer = player;

// play the muted audio
[mPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 7 there is also a `muted` property on `AVPlayer`:

```
@property (nonatomic, getter=isMuted) BOOL muted NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 7_0);
```